# How can we store a string containing Pre-Defined Macros into a variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, macros, printf

The problem is that; when I'm trying to store some string containing pre-defined macros into a variable compiler is giving me an error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100] = "This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = %s and time is = %s.\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__;
    return 0;
}
```

And the error is

```
yyy.c: In function 'main':
yyy.c:5:111: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant
     char string[100] = "This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = %s and time is = %s.\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__;
                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~
```

And when I'm trying with the below syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100] = ("This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = %s and time is = %s.\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    return 0;
}
```

The error that occurred is

```
yyy.c: In function 'main':
yyy.c:5:24: error: invalid initializer
     char string[100] = ("This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = %s and time is = %s.\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                        ^
```

but when I'm printing the same line with print statement i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = %s and time is = %s.\n\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    return 0;
}
```

There is no error and the output is

```
This line is appended using C programe and,
The data is = Jul  9 2021 and time is = 11:32:06.
```

Comment: Use `sprintf` to get the behavior of `printf`, but store the results in a string.

Comment: `char string[] = "date is " __DATE__ ", time is " __TIME__;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below syntax it will work

```
char str[] = "This line is appended using C programe and,\nThe data is = "__DATE__
                 " and time is = "__TIME__
                 ".\n\n";
```

Comment: Please explain why it will work. To most users the lack of operators might be confusing. (You already have my upvote, but explaining might get you more.... ;-) )  And consider mentioning/crediting any relation to the comment by @HolyBlackCat. (Though, strictly, anybody giving an answer in a comment can't complain if it is turned into an explained answer....)

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree with the first part of your comment. A description of what this is doing will improve the answer. But I disagree about the creditng part. It's not need here. There is nothing special in the comment that other C programmers could not know.

Comment: Hmm, I think being the first bringing up something which everybody should know (but probably not everybody actually does) into a problem discussion which is solved by it IS creditable. I also think that HolyBlackCat would not actually complain. But for relatively new users it is a habit to be adopted and fostered to look out for similar answers and comments and know when to make an answer and when to politely recognise others input.

Answer (score 1):

The `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros expand to string constants during compilation, so what you effectively did is giving a list of three string constants in a single variable declaration:

```
char string[100] = "one string", "another string", "yet another one";
```

This doesn't fit a structure of a declaration. The string constant is an initializer to a variable and you can't give three initializers to one variable.

You could declare several variables with one declaration and give a separate initializer to each of them:

```
char string1[100] = "one string", string2[30] = "another string", string3[50] = "yet another one";
```

and that's why your compiler expects an identifier—another variable's name—after the comma.

But that's obviously not what you intend. Anyway, you'd have to concatenate them before printing or print them all in sequence to get a desired output.

Another way is concatenating them at the syntax level. The C language supports such concatenation of constants:

```
"this is"    " a "     "sing"   "le str"    "ing"
```

represents a constant

```
"this is a single string"
```

So, you can do

```
char string[] = "The date is " __DATE__ " and time is " __TIME__ ".\n";
```

to declare and define a *single* string resulting from joining five *constants*.

Please note that I omitted the array length in the declaration. When the array is initialized with an explicit initializer, the missing size is automatically computed during compilation to fit the given string length.